# ajax datables not responsive

Tags: php, ajax

I am fetching data through database using ajax but i am bit confused how to show delete button here.
here is my ajax code.

```
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "ajax/fetch_notify.php", true);
    ajax.send();
 
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
 
            var html = "";
            var delete_notify = $('#delete_notify')
            for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
                var id = data[a].id;
                var date = data[a].date;
                var notify_alert = data[a].notify_alert;
                var fa_icon = data[a].fa_icon;
                var bg_color = data[a].bg_color;
                html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + id + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + date + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + notify_alert + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + fa_icon + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + bg_color + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + delete_notify+ "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
        }
    };
```

here is my delete button code.

```
<td>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="notify_id" name="notify_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
<button type="submit" id="delete_notify" name="delete_notify" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></form>
</td>
```

Comment: The code shown above isn't ajax (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), it's javascript. I see the 'Delete' variable being used in in your table building loop, but don't see it being defined any where. Could you please update your code example?

Comment: There is no variable named `Delete` i just put it for telling.

Comment: I paste full code now.

Comment: 'var delete_notify = $('#delete_notify')', this is jquery. Are you using jquey in this project? Everything else seems to be written in vanilajs.

Comment: `var delete_notify = $('#delete_notify')` i'm not using it on my code i just put here for reference.

Comment: So the delete button/form your showing here is in php. I'm assuming this rendered before the javascript is loaded. Does php  `$row['id']` correspond with js `$row['id']`?

Comment: `onreadystatechange` should be set **before** the `send` -  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not clear to me however, what I may suggest based on my assumptions of your code is.

```
$('#delete_notify')
```

This is a jquery code that is accessing only this button

```
<button type="submit" id="delete_notify" name="delete_notify" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

You should put the button within a form so that form gets submitted.

Comment: I think that `<form action="" method="POST">` is a form :)

Comment: <form action="" method="POST"> this one is used may be in another example... because it is clear that form was generated in an iteration of php loop... he is trying to apply the similar code into JS. As far as the code is clear, he is just inserting the delete button, not the form.